# Using Django's templating engine without the rest of Django

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm building an application, that uses the Django templating engine / language to "compile" some HTML. However, the app doesn't run on Django, and doesn't have all the config and stuff.
When I try to use it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Send.py", line 33, in <module>
    template = loader.get_template("email.html")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist: email.html
```

The code I am using is the following:

```
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.conf import settings

template = loader.get_template("email.html")
rendered = template.render(data)
```

The template is in the same directory as the Python file.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98135/how-do-i-use-django-templates-without-the-rest-of-django)

Comment: Here's an answer that works on Django >= 1.8 http://stackoverflow.com/a/34494931/817277

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) instead of Django templates as a standalone solution.

Comment: I second that. If you're already familiar with Django templates you'll know how to use Jinja2. They are almost identical but Jinja is better imho.

Comment: Jinja2 python3 support is still experimental

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to use this?

```
settings.configure(TEMPLATE_DIRS=('.',))
```

Since the templates are in the same directory as the python code, this should be enough for the loader to find the template.

Answer (score 3):

In order for the loader to find your templates; you need to have the directory where the templates are located in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` tuple in `settings.py`. By default django will search for a `templates` directory *inside an application* so if you don't have an application registered; django cannot find templates.

If you are after a "django like" template engine, [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) is very close to django's syntax and is completely self-contained, you won't run into unexpected issues as you are facing now.