# Use Django templates and tags without the rest of Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I want to use Django for templating, but am not building a web-app. Basically, most of my question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98135/how-do-i-use-django-templates-without-the-rest-of-django). But I also need to use a certain tag, which is not a custom tag by me (as addressed in one of the answers), but the `mathfilters` filters installed with `pip`. How can I use them in this context?

I read everywhere to rather use something like `Jinja` for this, but that would be a last resort.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but have you tried to create a template and do `{% load mathfilters %}` on the top? Does it work?

Comment: No, I somehow need to acquaint Django with the mathfilters app, but I don't know how. I thing usually this would be done in the `settings.py` which I don't use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`settings.configure()` accepts settings as keyword arguments. To activate `mathfilters`, simply add it to `INSTALLED_APP` like you would do in `settings.py`:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(INSTALLED_APPS=['mathfilters'])
django.setup()
```

Then you can use `{% load mathfilters %}` to load the tags and filters. Note that since Django 1.7 you need to call `django.setup()` after you've configured your settings.

Comment: That would've been it … turns out switching to Jinja was not so hard.